# apply patch to richfaces 3.3.3

Tags: maven, richfaces, patch

I've no experience with maven or applying patches.

I'd like to apply the patch as described on https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-12062?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=12677932#comment-12677932 to the richfaces library.

I've downloaded the richfaces 3.3.3.Final sources from http://www.jboss.org/richfaces/download/stable

I can however not find the WebXml.java file. Do I have to execute some maven command to add some additional sources?

Comment: the file can bi found in richfaces-ui-3.3.3.Final\framework\impl\src\main\java\org\ajax4jsf\webapp\WebXml.java, you can also patch the code manualy and theb build it via mvn clean install. I've tried to build it via maven3 but the build has a legacy repo and as far as I qnow maven3 does not allow legacy repos so I got an ERROR, I will try to build it via maven2

Comment: Thanx simonC! it worked! I've made my first steps in maven. The build stopped while building the richfaces-demo part but the impl package was already build by then. I've also added 2 missing dependency's. Just tested my application with the new library and it seems to work. Can I somehow mark this comment as the solution?

Comment: Sorry @LuiggiMendoza I ment to mark simonC's comment as the solution ;-). And I'll gladly accept his post!

Comment: @gadeynebram can you post a link to your jar I still have problems im my app, look my answer below

Comment: Hi @simonC, here's a link to my jar [link](http://www.bramgadeyne.be/richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final-firefox11patch.jar). I also use a rich:tree but I don't get this error. When does it occur? On drag and drop or something?

Comment: @gadeynebram tnx your lib works...I had the problem every time I've rerendered the three...it looks that my build was not so successful as yours ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the file can bi found in richfaces-ui-3.3.3.Final\framework\impl\src\main\java\org\ajax4jsf\webapp\WebXml‌​.java, you can also patch the code manualy and then build it via mvn clean install. I've tried to build it via maven3 but the build has a legacy repo and as far as I qnow maven3 does not allow legacy repos so I got an ERROR

I've tried then the maven2 build some tests failed but the jar was built, I had to manualy install facelets jar in maven and tune the maven heap memory options like this :

**export MAVEN_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx2548M -XX:+UseCompressedOops"**

Unfortunalty it doesnt help for my problem I still get the folowing error when using **rich:tree**

**Caused by: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: invalid literal/length code**

But it looks like that @gadeynebram probelm was solved.